# Ruby method to generate control character?

Tags: ruby, string, jruby, control-characters

If I want to add a control character to a string, is there a method to do so? I tried looking at the regexp class in the API, but that only seems to be relevant when you are *searching* for a control character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use format like `\cx` in double quoted string to represent [control character x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29).

For instance:

```
"\cA\cD\cH"
#=> "\u0001\u0004\b"
```

For single character strings, this could also work:

```
?\C-A
#=> "\u0001"
?\C-H
#=> "\b"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. If I use ctrlD = "\cD" and then place the variable in a string like so `#{ctrlD}`, will it succesfully place the EOT control character in the string?